# Correct way to cast a list of objects from a parent class to various child classes

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base class called `Game` and multiple child classes such as `NFLGame`, `NBAGame`, `NHLGame`, and so on, and in my code, I'm putting a bunch of these child objects into an array defined as:

`ArrayList<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();`

And then to read each game in the array I can think of two options of how to access them.

1. Make a long `if/else if` chain or a `switch` to check which child class the game belongs to using `instanceof()` and then cast it to the correct child class.
2. Use a hash table technique that uses a key id that is assigned to every child class and have the value be a call to an interface method that casts to the correct child class. I should add that this is the method I am currently using because eventually I want to add a lot more leagues which would make this a more cleaner and efficient approach.

But my question is: are these the only two options available when reading objects of multiple child classes from a list/array or is there a better way to go about this?

EDIT:

As requested here is my Game class:

```
public abstract class Game
{
    private String mHomeTeamName, mAwayTeamName, mGameStartTimeLocal, mHomeTeamLogoSrc, mAwayTeamLogoSrc;
    private String mHomeTeamFullName, mAwayTeamFullName;
    private String mHomeTeamRecord, mAwayTeamRecord, mHomeTeamScore, mAwayTeamScore;
    private boolean mGameEnded, mIsGamePostponed, mIsChecked;
    private boolean mWasAddedToCheckedGamesMap;
    private int mLeagueID;
    private String mLeagueName, mGameDateTimeUTC, mGameDateUTC, mGameID;
    private Date mGameDate;

    public Game(int leagueID, String leagueName)
    {
        mLeagueID = leagueID;
        mLeagueName = leagueName;
    }

    public Game(String homeTeam, String homeTeamFullName, String awayTeam, String awayTeamFullName,
                String gameStartTimeLocal, String homeTeamRecord, String awayTeamRecord, String homeTeamLogoSrc,
                String awayTeamLogoSrc, String homeTeamScore, String awayTeamScore, boolean gameEnded,
                boolean isGamePostponed, String leagueName, int leagueID, Date gameDate,
                String gameDateTimeUTC, String gameDateUTC)
    {
        mHomeTeamName = homeTeam;
        mAwayTeamName = awayTeam;
        mHomeTeamFullName = homeTeamFullName;
        mAwayTeamFullName = awayTeamFullName;
        mGameStartTimeLocal = gameStartTimeLocal;
        mHomeTeamRecord = homeTeamRecord;
        mAwayTeamRecord = awayTeamRecord;
        mHomeTeamLogoSrc = homeTeamLogoSrc;
        mAwayTeamLogoSrc = awayTeamLogoSrc;
        mHomeTeamScore = homeTeamScore;
        mAwayTeamScore = awayTeamScore;
        mGameEnded = gameEnded;
        mIsGamePostponed = isGamePostponed;
        mLeagueName = leagueName;
        mLeagueID = leagueID;
        mGameDate = gameDate;
        mGameDateUTC = gameDateUTC;
        mGameDateTimeUTC = gameDateTimeUTC;
        mIsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Offhand, it sounds like you're approaching the problem from a wrong direction (i.e., what we call [The X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223467)). Why would you even want to do this? The point of polymorphism is having a shared interface, and each class implementing **the same methods** according to their own logic, so you don't even need to cast them.

Comment: Can you share some actual code (or even pseudo-code) of the methods in `Game` and what you want your for loop to do, so we have something concrete to discuss? That would help me giving a clearer answer.

Comment: @Mureinik okay I think see what you mean but what about those child classes that have different methods that the base class should not be implementing?

Comment: Either have abstract or empty methods in the base class, or rethink your design - if you're iterating a list of `Game` objects, you shouldn't be calling specific `NBAGame` methods.

Comment: @Mureinik added my Game class code. So it's basically all the attributes that will be needed in every game. Then the child classes NBAGame, NFLGame, etc would implement methods specific to their need. (Not showing all the getters/setters.)

Comment: Off-topic: You will soon find it useful to create a `Team` class as well.

Comment: @Marvin that's true. But I'm only working with team-based leagues for now.

Comment: Another option is to use multiple lists. If you (absolutely) need to access methods of each specific subtype you should not ambiguate and put them in a list of `Game`.

Comment: @JornVernee what if I end up having 20 different leagues? That would imply working with 20 different lists. Doesn't sound better than what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Well, if 20 different leagues means having 20 different interfaces, that's just how it's going to be. You'll need to know each specific subtype. But Mureinik is right, you should try to define the abstract behaviour of a `Game` in the `Game` class, and implement that same interface with each subclass. Then there is no need to know the different types.

Comment: @JornVernee I see what you mean. My only gripe is it seems like I'll have to write the same code for a lot of methods when I create a new league class, which defeats the purpose of the don't-repeat-code principle. But I appreciate the help! I'm going to try the suggestion given in the answer and if it doesn't work or something, I think I'll go with this approach.

Comment: Well, that's something people here could help with. You could, for instance, give a default implementation in the abstract class and only override it within the subtypes that need to. It would be useful to know what different things you're doing with each type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you need is the **visitor pattern** (see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)).

The idea is to add a method in your game class `accept(Visitor visitor)` that is overridden in each subclasses (NBAGame, etc). Implementation is basically something like `visitor.visit(this)`.

To construct an interface `Visitor` with appropriate visiting methods `visit(NBAGame)`, `visit(NHLGame)` and so on.

To implement that `Visitor` interface to make what you need with each element type.

Then to call `accept` with a chosen visitor to every element of your collection.

The underlying mechanism is called the **double dispatch** (see [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)).

No cast, no if, no instanceof.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I will look more into this.

Comment: When you will be aware about that pattern, you will then use it every time you need a hierarchy of concepts and collections of. Easy.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! It works perfectly. Thank you. For anyone reading this, a really good Youtube tutorial on how to implement this pattern is found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pL4mOUDi54o).